# ¿Cambiar valor checkbox de booleano a string java EE?

Tags: mysql, string, java-ee, checkbox

Mi aplicación está formada por un formulario con varios inputs de tipo text, uno de tipo file y otro de tipo checkbox.
El input checkbox va a servir para marcar un objeto como favorito.

Los valores van dirigidos a un servlet.

Dichos valores van a ser registrados a mi base de datos(MySQL), y la columna de favoritos es de tipo varchar.

Actualmente el checkbox tiene dos valores true y false, según está activado o no. Mi intención es obtener el valor de éste input de forma String, ya que cuando el checkbox no está marcado, me salta una excepción de tipo null, y cuando está marcado, no me registra el valor correcto a mi tabla de la base de datos.

¿Es posible cambiar el valor booleano del checkbox a string?

Aquí os dejo mi formulario, por si os sirve:

```js
<form id="Login" role="form" method="POST"
     action="../ModificarJuego" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="uuid" id="uuid" value="<%=jaux.getUuid() %>">
     <div class="form-group">

      <label class="control-label" for="titulo">Título:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo" name="titulo" value="<%=jaux.getTitulo()%>">

     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="genero">Género:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="genero"
       name="genero" value="<%=jaux.getGenero()%>">

     </div>

     <div class="form-group">

      <label class="control-label" for="descripcion">Descripción:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" value="<%=jaux.getDescripcion()%>">

     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="caratula">Carátula:</label>
      <br/>
      <img alt="caratula" src="image.jsp?idJuego=<%=jaux.getIdJuego() %>" style="width:75px; height: 75px;">
      <input type="file" class="form-control" id="caratula" name="caratula"> 

     </div>
     
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="caratula">Añadir a favoritos:</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="checkbox"  id="favorito" name="favorito" value="1"> 
     </div>
     
     <br />
     <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Aplicar Cambios">
     </div>
```

Aquí el servlet del formulario:

```js
package es.cj.controller;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

import es.cj.bean.Conexion;
import es.cj.bean.Juego;
import es.cj.bean.Usuario;
import es.cj.dao.JuegoDAO;
import es.cj.dao.JuegoDAOimpl;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ModificarJuego
 */
@MultipartConfig
public class ModificarJuego extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
  */
 public ModificarJuego() {
  super();
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
  *      response)
  */
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
 }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
  *      response)
  */
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {
  String titulo = request.getParameter("titulo");
  String genero = request.getParameter("genero");
  String descripcion = request.getParameter("descripcion");
  String uuid = request.getParameter("uuid");

  HttpSession session = request.getSession();
  int idUsuario = ((Usuario) session.getAttribute("usuarioWeb")).getIdUsuario();
  
  
  
  // Añadir a favoritos
  String fav = request.getParameter("favorito");
  
  
  
  
  
  // Caratula
  Part filePart = request.getPart("caratula");

  InputStream inputS = null;
  ByteArrayOutputStream os = null;

  Juego jue = null;

  if (!getFileName(filePart).equals("")) {
   inputS = filePart.getInputStream();
   // Escalar imagen
   BufferedImage imageBuffer = ImageIO.read(inputS);
   Image tmp = imageBuffer.getScaledInstance(220, 220, BufferedImage.SCALE_FAST);
   BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(220, 220, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   buffered.getGraphics().drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);

   os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   ImageIO.write(buffered, "jpg", os);

   jue = new Juego(titulo, genero, descripcion, os.toByteArray(), null, uuid, idUsuario, fav);
  } else {
   jue = new Juego(titulo, genero, descripcion, null, null, uuid, idUsuario, fav);
  }

  //
  
  

  JuegoDAO jDAO = new JuegoDAOimpl();

  ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
  String usu = sc.getInitParameter("usuario");
  String pass = sc.getInitParameter("password");
  String driver = sc.getInitParameter("driver");
  String bd = sc.getInitParameter("database");

  Conexion conex = new Conexion(usu, pass, driver, bd);

  jDAO.modificar(conex, jue);

  response.sendRedirect("jsp/principalJuegos.jsp");

 }

 private Object getFileName(Part filePart) {
  for (String content : filePart.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
   if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
    return content.substring(content.indexOf("=") + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
   }
  }
  return null;

 }

}
```

Y aquí la query:

```js
package es.cj.dao;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import es.cj.bean.Conexion;
import es.cj.bean.Juego;
import es.cj.bean.Usuario;

public class JuegoDAOimpl implements JuegoDAO {

 public List<Juego> listar(Conexion c, Usuario u) {
  List<Juego> juegos = new ArrayList<Juego>();

  String sql = "SELECT * FROM juegos WHERE idUsuario = ?";
  try {
   PreparedStatement sentencia = c.getConector().prepareStatement(sql);
   sentencia.setInt(1, u.getIdUsuario());
   ResultSet resultado = sentencia.executeQuery();
   while (resultado.next()) {
    Juego auxiliar = new Juego(resultado.getInt("idJuego"), resultado.getString("titulo"),
      resultado.getString("genero"), resultado.getString("descripcion"),
      resultado.getBytes("caratula"), resultado.getBytes("backup"), resultado.getString("uuid"),
      resultado.getInt("idUsuario"), resultado.getString("favoritos"));
    juegos.add(auxiliar);
   }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return juegos;
 }

 public byte[] obtenerCaratula(Conexion c, int idJuego) {
  byte[] imagen = null;

  String sql = "SELECT caratula FROM juegos WHERE idJuego = ?";
  try {
   PreparedStatement sentencia = c.getConector().prepareStatement(sql);
   sentencia.setInt(1, idJuego);
   ResultSet resultado = sentencia.executeQuery();
   while (resultado.next()) {
    imagen = resultado.getBytes("caratula");
   }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return imagen;
  
 }

 public void eliminar(Conexion c, String uuid) {
  
  String sql = "DELETE FROM juegos WHERE uuid = ?";
  
  try {
   PreparedStatement sentencia = c.getConector().prepareStatement(sql);
   sentencia.setString(1, uuid);
   sentencia.executeUpdate();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
 }

 @Override
 public void insertar(Conexion conex, Juego jue) {
  String sql = "INSERT INTO juegos VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  try {
   PreparedStatement sentencia = conex.getConector().prepareStatement(sql);
   sentencia.setString(1, jue.getTitulo());
   sentencia.setString(2, jue.getGenero());
   sentencia.setString(3, jue.getDescripcion());
   sentencia.setBytes(4, jue.getCaratula());
   sentencia.setBytes(5, jue.getBackup());
   sentencia.setInt(6, jue.getIdUsuario());
   sentencia.setString(7, jue.getUuid());
   sentencia.setString(8, jue.getFavoritos());
   
   sentencia.executeUpdate();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
 }

 @Override
 public Juego obtenerJuegoPorUUID(Conexion conex, String uuid) {
  Juego jaux = new Juego();
  
  String sql = "SELECT * FROM juegos WHERE uuid = ?";
  try {
   PreparedStatement sentencia = conex.getConector().prepareStatement(sql);
   sentencia.setString(1, uuid);
   ResultSet resultado = sentencia.executeQuery();
   while (resultado.next()) {
    jaux = new Juego(resultado.getInt("idJuego"), resultado.getString("titulo"),
      resultado.getString("genero"), resultado.getString("descripcion"),
      resultado.getBytes("caratula"), resultado.getBytes("backup"), resultado.getString("uuid"),
      resultado.getInt("idUsuario"), resultado.getString("favoritos"));
   }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return jaux;
 }

 @Override
 public void modificar(Conexion conex, Juego jue) {
  
  
  try {
   if (jue.getCaratula() != null) {
    
    String sql = "UPDATE juegos SET titulo=?, genero=?, descripcion=?, caratula=?, favoritos=? WHERE uuid=?";
    PreparedStatement sentencia = conex.getConector().prepareStatement(sql);
    sentencia.setString(1, jue.getTitulo());
    sentencia.setString(2, jue.getGenero());
    sentencia.setString(3, jue.getDescripcion());
    sentencia.setBytes(4, jue.getCaratula());
    sentencia.setString(5, jue.getFavoritos());
    sentencia.setString(6, jue.getUuid());
    
    sentencia.executeUpdate();
   } else {
    String sql = "UPDATE juegos SET titulo=?, genero=?, descripcion=?, favoritos=? WHERE uuid=?";
    PreparedStatement sentencia = conex.getConector().prepareStatement(sql);
    sentencia.setString(1, jue.getTitulo());
    sentencia.setString(2, jue.getGenero());
    sentencia.setString(3, jue.getDescripcion());
    sentencia.setString(4, jue.getFavoritos());
    sentencia.setString(5, jue.getUuid());
    
    sentencia.executeUpdate();
   }
   
   
   
   
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
 }

 
 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero haber comprendido tu necesidad.

Punto número 1 debes validar tu formulario para que el checkbox siempre tenga un valor al momento de hacer el POST. O viene con true o false.

Ahora bien en tu servlet ¿cómo llega el valor cuando lo recuperas con "String fav = request.getParameter("favorito");"?

Seguro que como se menciona true o false, entonces ya es String y así lo deberías de almacenar en tu tabla cuyo campo tiene tipo de dato varchar que supongo no permite valores nulos -null-.